# How to add Geo data to a google contact via People api?

Tags: javascript, python, geolocation, google-people-api

I am trying to add geo data to the contacts I am inserting/updating into/on
the google contacts using the Python/java api but I can not find any reference as to where this latitude longitude data should go.
of course adding them as a custom field works find but then it is not really adding it as a real geo datapoint

as you can see here:
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#address

there is no mention of geo data atll.

Comment: I don't see an option to do this on the Web UI either,it appears that adding Lat/Long as geolocation data is not possible yet, this could be a good candidate for a Feature Idea that you could submit at https://developers.google.com/people/support#developer_product_feedback

Comment: but when you try to save a google map business  it actually inserts it right in there.

Comment: You are claiming that a record created by Google Map Business has the same properties as a record created by Google People, That is not necessarily true.

Comment: Besides searching for address, search the Google People API for location, latitude, longitude